# Skyrim - How could I change my character?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

Okay so I started playing Skyrim yesterday and I am currently level 22, I currently have a Wood Elf Archer + Stealth.
He does alchemy to earn money as well as sell off items that I steal, he is part of the Thieves guild.

So I want to improve him or maybe even change the gameplay style completely, first thing is I am thinking of going Vampire Lord as his alternate form, they look rather good although I am unaware of the disadvantages socially.
I ask this because I want a sort of barter character, but is still able to do some damage bolstered by poisons I make via alchemy.
I rather enjoy the Archer gameplay style but I was thinking of adding Pickpocket into the style so I can use bow for the times when it is needed and use poisons via placement to kill the target, similar to frag pockets in fallout.

So what is the maximum amount of points your character earns at the top level, I am unsure of what the final level can be without using legendary skills.
I do have a mod that allows me to reset my points also so if that is necessary then I can.

TL;DR version is this.
I want to change my character, what social effects does being a vampire lord present, such as do characters not interact and attack on site?.
Also how could I build my character so he makes money via pickpocket, alchemy and bartering (Speech skill) but with a side of Archery for dealing with the dragons and anyone who actually sees me (incorporating stealth into the build.)

If you need more information about my character please ask, I will give as much as I can.

Thanks

Comment: This question is about 4 different questions at once, which would be better asked separately. Multi-part questions don't really fit our Q&A format.

Answer (score 2):

The [level cap](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Skills_%28Skyrim%29) is 81, without using legendary skills.  With them, there is no cap, but the game can get very grindy and annoying.  You don't need a mod to reset perks; this can be done in *Dragonborn* at the cost of one dragon soul per skill tree, or [with the developer console](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_%28Skyrim%29#Player_commands) on PC.

[Vampire Lords](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Vampire_Lord) are ordinary vampires, and suffer the same limitations.  Other people will not be automatically hostile if you have *Dawnguard* installed, unless you're in full Vampire Lord form (which is probably a Bad Idea in any event, so make sure you quicksave first and record it for posterity).

> Also how could I build my character so he makes money via pickpocket, alchemy and bartering (Speech skill) but with a side of Archery for dealing with the dragons and anyone who actually sees me (incorporating stealth into the build.)

To get better at something, do it a lot.

- Alchemy and speech can be trivially practiced at low levels, though you probably won't earn much money initially.  The [Black Market](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Market) power is helpful for large-scale speechcraft leveling, and also for more general junk-elimination.
- Pickpocketing is more challenging since you don't want to get caught at low levels.  It's possible to pickpocket draugr and most other enemies, and you generally won't get arrested for it.
- Archery is just a matter of practice and having a decent bow.  Of course, you the player will also need to be good at aiming.  Archery also dovetails nicely with sneak, since you get bonus damage for attacking an enemy unaware of you.
- Sneak is trivially leveled.  Just sneak whenever you're in a dungeon.  If there are enemies nearby, you will level the skill automatically.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, that was very detailed. I need to purchase Dragonborn I think to get some new stuff in which you have mentioned